# i have facing issue like : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. > Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, build.gradle, manifest

i have facing manifest merger error. i don't know why this error are occur.
Please help me. i have declare both code of android manifest and module build gradle.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="ep.pathtec.authentication"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

<!--<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />-->

<permission
    android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission     android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.maps.android.utils.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<!-- This app has permission to register with GCM and receive message -->
<!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED -->
<permission
    android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

 <uses-permission  android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
 <!-- The two elements above ensure that only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<!-- Don't require camera, as this requires a rear camera. This allows it to work on the Nexus 7 -->
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false"/>
 <!-- TODO replace above two with next line after Android 4.2 -->
 <!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"/> -->
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false"/>
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape"/>
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false"/>
 <!-- This excludes Google TV, which is unfortunately included by virtue of  not requiring a camera -->
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"/>
 <!-- TODO make this not required again after android.hardware.camera.any is available AIzaSyAkzuP87BMO01aaCX_JsDQR4-klIys-lCM-->

 <application
    android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.PathTec"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="false"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:manageSpaceActivity=".ManageSpaceActivity">
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDuSzHtwlE8JBzn1kCWnEeQfG1SF_9bIPI"/>
     <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.Login"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.Home"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.jobdetails.JobList"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="My Jobs"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.jobdetails.JobDetailsContainer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.Passcord"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.jobdetails.JobRouteContainer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.jobdetails.Signature"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.jobdetails.NoteEditor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.clientform.ClientFormContainer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ManageSpaceActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:theme="@style/CaptureTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Allow web apps to launch Barcode Scanner by linking to http://zxing.appspot.com/scan. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="zxing.appspot.com"
                android:path="/scan"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- We also support a Google Product Search URL. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <!--   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />-->
            <data
                android:host="www.google.com"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- And the UK version. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <!--    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
-->
            <data
                android:host="www.google.co.uk"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- Support zxing://scan/?... like iPhone app -->
        <intent-filter>
            <!--  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />->

            <data
                android:host="scan"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="zxing"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity"
        android:label="@string/preferences_name"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This allows us to handle sharing any plain text . -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.book.SearchBookContentsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/sbc_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SEARCH_BOOK_CONTENTS"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.share.ShareActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="user"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SHARE"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.history.HistoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/history_title"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.share.BookmarkPickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/bookmark_picker_name"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.share.AppPickerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_picker_name"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.HelpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="user">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.message.MessageContainer"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="Messages"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>
    <activity
        android:name="ep.pathtec.message.MessageEditor"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/pathtec.Theme"/>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>

            <category android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name="ep.pathtec.scheduler.NetWorkChangeListener"
        android:label="NetworkConnection">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="ep.pathtec.scheduler.GPSTracker"/>
    <service android:name="ep.pathtec.scheduler.SessionTracker"/>
    <service android:name="ep.pathtec.scheduler.SyncAdapter"/>
    <service android:name="ep.pathtec.scheduler.AppLock"/>
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>
    <service android:name="ep.pathtec.gcm.GCMClientRegistration"/>
    <service android:name="ep.pathtec.gcm.GCMClientUnRegistration"/>
    <service android:name="ep.pathtec.scheduler.NoteSyncAdapter"/>

    <provider
        android:name="ep.pathtec.db.DBProvider"
        android:authorities="ep.pathtec.authentication.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:multiprocess="false">
    </provider>
 </application>

 </manifest>
```

and my Module build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 15
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ep.pathtec.authentication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    multiDexEnabled true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
  }
  }

  dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
  compile files('libs/crittercism_v4_4_0_sdkonly.jar')
  compile files('libs/jackson-all-1.9.0.jar')
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
  }
```

Comment: please post your error log here

Comment: @RahulSharma Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

Comment: @user7374191 show `see logs`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya  saw tab but i cant find the issue..

Comment: @user7374191 need `</intent-filter>` here `<!-- Support zxing://scan/?... like iPhone app -->`

Comment: @user7374191 remove `<intent-filter>` after `<!-- Support zxing://scan/?... like iPhone app `

Comment: after change `clean-rebuild` and run

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya No changes after comment 'Intent-filter tag'

Comment: @user7374191 multiple error happening .check another tag.step by step approach .

Comment: Problem Solve when i remove below code from AndroidManifest.xml file.

android:theme="@style/CaptureTheme"

Answer (score 1):

If you using external library add `tools:node="replace"` inside application tag:

```
<application
    android:name="ep.pathtec.authentication.PathTec"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="false"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:manageSpaceActivity=".ManageSpaceActivity"

    tools:node="replace">
```